# USB3.0 high speed data lines routing

Tags: pcb, usb

I've done a PCB design where I've got a USB3.0 interface using non-standard connectors.
The interface got a hub with 4 USB3.0 data lines and after a intensive tests only one channel runs into instability and communication drops out after a few seconds streaming data, fortunately the other three channels work fine.

I'm into the layout revision process for that 'problematic' channel, and the only difference I found compared to the rest is that the data lines are passing very close to a crystal clock oscillator output, I wonder if this could be the issue....

To make an idea this is a snapshot of the area (the 'bad' channel is routed to J8):

[image]

As a first thought, I'm thinking to move/shift the tracks to the right about 2mm.

Does anyone know if this could be the main issue and moving them 2mm could be enough?

Comment: Yes. Why were they crowded so close to the crystal in the first place?

Comment: Why didn’t you guard the signals with a gnd track and recompute Z.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, sorry I should mention that detail in my question, the tracks went so close to the crystal because those connector had initially a support holes where one of them was within the gap below the yellow mark, now we don't need them so I've got more room.

Comment: A couple of questions...
1. How many layers is this board? 2. Did you design to the recommended impedance of USB 3.0? Tony's comment about using and to guard the signal is a good idea. I would probably use ground vias rather than ground "track". Also a pretty common rule is to distance signals 3*track width from each other.
https://www.edn.com/getting-emc-design-right-first-time-part-7-crosstalk/

Comment: What kind of differential pair did you design for? What impedance? Is there a ground plane beneath the diff pair (what is the stackup)

Comment: What about the short distance where the red and blue pairs go parallel above the yellow mark? I would also move both of the blue ones a bit to the right to also solve this

Comment: The data lines are too close, use a ground plane to filter the noise. Also, the crystal will be interfering with the data line.

Comment: Why do you think that the "problrmatic channel" is due to your little (and unnecessry) wiggling, and not in the nonstandard connector and nonstandard cable? Did you check diffimpedance, NEXT, and FEXT for the entire channel? https://www.flukenetworks.com/blog/cabling-chronicles/cable-testing-101-cross-talk-near-and-far

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll try to clarify most of the questions, 
The USB3.0 lines are properly designed to match impedance and length following the specification. The board is 8 layers. And I'd like to clarify again that the rest of the channels work fine after intensive long tests and checks there're not errors in the bus and the transmission works perfect. Only that first channel gives errors, do you think that shifting the lines to the right 2mm would help?

Comment: have you looked at the eye diagram for all the traces?

Comment: Have you looked/scanned the relevant USB3 frequency ranges with an EMI probe and spectrum analyzer? Do you see the crystal's harmonics in those frequency ranges? Have you isolated the issue to be the crystal?

Comment: Differential pairs MUST be routed as far apart as possible, to avoid cross-talk. Your board not only has unnecessary trace density near the oscillator, but the Rx and Tx pairs go together for much longer distance than your other channel.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, thanks for the recommendation I've moved  those tracks away the oscillator as much as possible....the channel different distances are not an issue, according USB3 specification every channel is independent of the other in that sense, the prove is that (it is not shown in the above image) there's another channel on the board which is way larger  than the others and all of them work perfectly together. I say again, only that first top channel is the problematic the rest or them work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the oscillator and mount it to a different part of the board with some wires. It may affect the oscillators performance but it should help you prove if the oscillator is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately oscillator can't move to other part of the board, following manufacturer recommendations it has to be there.
Following the above comments I've shifted the tracks to the right ~2mm and route a ground track in between (oscillator and USB3 lines) trying to isolate as much as possible any possible interference.